# web.xml in jboss-javaee-webapp-ear-blank-archtype

Tags: java, jboss, web.xml

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
    file name references to "index.xhtml" that does not exist in web content    web.xml /Test-web/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF   line 18 Web XML Problem

web.xml in Project is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd ">
 <context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
  <param-value>Development</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I always have this problem with the file web.xml . help me, and I don't any problem in netbeans and this problem is eclipse kepler.

Comment: Do you have file `index.xhtml` in the `webapp` folder? As a welcome page this is what the application looks for in `webapp` when the application is started and if you have another page you should replace `index.xhtml` with that file.

Comment: yes, i has an `index.xhtml` file in `webapp` as welcome page, and don't another page in webapp.

Comment: What is the complete exception? It is not enough what you gave up there in your question.

Comment: I After run project give this error.


![localhost:8080/Test][1]


![localhost:8080/Test/index.xhtml][2]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/K0K0y.png
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/aQbBB.png


my problem this is after run project, i don't see welcome page.

Comment: Check JBoss `server.log` for more information. This alone is not enough for you to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Solved. I just go to Test Directory and type command under:

    `mvn clean
    mvn install
    mvn package`

and after above command, run project ear  on server.
Also, add dependency to maven, inclusive javax-faces package of jsf.

Comment: Good to know. You can do all those maven steps in Eclipse Kepler too by right clicking on your project if it is already a maven project and then choose `Run As`and you will see the `maven clean`, `maven install` etc. If your project is not yet a maven you can convert it first to a maven project.